# jquery - filter on multiple prefixes

Tags: jquery, filter

How can I filter for all id's that begin with "pre" or "radio"?

```
$.each($(':input[id^="pre"]',':input[id^="radio"]').serializeArray(), function() {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your selector was a bit off:

```
$('input[id^="pre"], input[id^="radio"]').each(function () {});
```

or if you want to serialize the set of returned objects:

```
$('input[id^="pre"], input[id^="radio"]').serializeArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't break your selectors up as separate strings:

```
$(':input[id^="pre"], :input[id^="radio"]')
```

[Multiple selectors](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) are a single string.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhoerster/jxbcP/).  I think this is what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

`$(":input[id]").filter(function() { return this.id.match(/^(pre|radio)/)});`

Comment: I like this approach. Is the colon in input optional?

Comment: "input" just matches `<input>` tags, while ":input" "Selects all input, textarea, select and button elements" as said on http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/